# Change in one place the data about the company, which are placed on several pages

Tags: plugins, options

Some pages of the site contain information about the company. If something changes, then you need to change everything manually. Is there a way to change the data in one place and it will change throughout the site?

Comment: You can always search-and-replace the data directly via the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Block Editor, set up the information in one place and use the 3 dots menu to save your block as a Reusable Block. You can then add the block wherever you like throughout the site, and whenever you edit the contents, it will update in all locations.